# Documenting a method that just returns something

Tags: language-agnostic, documentation

I'm writing some javadocs (actually they are jsdocs but it doesn't make a difference for this question) and found this repeating pattern:

Imagine a method that just returns a value, maybe product of some calculation. For example, let say it is the time in milliseconds since the unix epoch.

```
public long getTimeSinceTheEpoch(){

  //calculate time

  return time;
}
```

So far, so good. Now when the time comes to add javadocs (or jsdocs, or rdocs, whatever), I've been writing something like this:

```
/**
* Gets the time in milliseconds since the unix epoch
*
* @returns the time in milliseconds since the unix epoch
*/
public long getTimeSinceTheEpoch(){
```

Here, the problem is obvious.

My question is, what do you put in the body of the comment, and what do you choose for the `@returns` attribute of the comment?

**IMPORTANT**

I'm not a fan of these kind of comments, if it depended on me I would rename the method to something like `getTimeInMillisecondsSinceTheEpoch` and avoid the comments at all.

I cannot do that (avoid the comments), so I'm striving to make them as useful as possible.

Comment: I'm afraid you already know the answer to this. Welcome to the hell that is known as meaningless standards.

Answer (score 1):

Best is to provide only the @return description as you need to document what you are returning for sure.

In the comment section, you could also throw in that same one-liner but also add *how* you are going to go about returning what you return, for e.g.

```
/**
* Gets the time in milliseconds since the unix epoch
* by doing something incredible.
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307142/documenting-a-method-that-just-returns-something
*
* @note thank you stackoverflow
*
* @returns the time in milliseconds since the unix epoch
*/
public long getTimeSinceTheEpoch(){
```

Answer (score 0):

The Sun (now Oracle) style guide "[How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide)" recommends this:

> The @return tag is required for every
>   method that returns something other
>   than void, even if it is redundant
>   with the method description. (Whenever
>   possible, find something non-redundant
>   (ideally, more specific) to use for
>   the tag comment.)

I'm not fond of the redundancy, and it goes against the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle. Personally, I either make one a summary and the other a detail (as suggested above), or provide only an @return. As you point out, the name of a simple getter may suffice as the summary.